# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Expected an int but was 68203991471 at line 1 column 25 path $.series_id

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am calling an api, it told me to use id as the endpoint path and the api will encode it to base36.

```
//const val id: Long = 68203991471
const val base36: String = "vbyw8mn"

interface ApiService {
    @GET("v1/series/{id}")
    suspend fun getWebtoonApi(@Path("id") id: Long = 68203991471): Response<WebtoonJson>
}

object RetrofitApi {
    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.mangaupdates.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
    val retrofitApi: ApiService = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
}
```

I tried to change the id to long and string, but it doesn't work.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.webtoon_gacha, PID: 27282
    com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Expected an int but was 68203991471 at line 1 column 25 path $.series_id
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:228)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:218)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:40)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:243)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:153)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@c36cdc, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]
    Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Expected an int but was 68203991471 at line 1 column 25 path $.series_id
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextInt(JsonReader.java:1172)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:226)
            ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kotlin's **Int** max value is [10 digits](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/numbers.html), and 68203991471 is 11 digits, so it correctly throws exception. try **Long** return type for **series_id** field instead.

Comment: It worked, thanks. It turns out that the plugin i used to map JSON data to kotlin data class mapped the type wrong, i changed so many type.

Comment: It also worked for Android